# mvc Url.Action generating an argumentexception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url.action

I have a menu containing various links to specific pages in my app.  One of them has just started exhibiting very strange behaviour.  Heres the markup

```
<li>
    <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contract",
        new { id = Model.ContractId, orgId = Model.OrgId })">
        <i class="fa fa-briefcase"></i>&nbsp;Contract Details
    </a>
</li>
```

The controller action method signature:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(int id, int orgId)
```

Whenever I click on the link I get this error:

> [ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.Parameter name:
>   name] System.Web.Mvc.ActionNameAttribute..ctor(String name) +99

The action exists, the controller exists, the parameters being passed have values, yet I get this error.  I've used exactly the same method on various other links in the same page, just to different controllers and they all work fine, it's just this one.  I can't see what the problem is.  Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: You have `[ActionName]` attribute somewhere (in said action or somewhere else in the controller) with an invalid `name` argument